# Move 3 or more objects at the same time but block them if one of them hit an obstacle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm kinda new to Unity and I was trying to make a Sokoban-like game. I found an issue with my code and I tried to fix it but it's not working as I'd like.

I would need to be able to push any pushable regardless if there's another pushable behind it as long as the last pushable on the row is not going to hit an obstacle.

I've managed to move 3 pushables at the same time but as soon as the last pushable hits an obstacle, the first pushable overlaps the next in the row.

```
 //We check if the pushable object is going to move where a obstacle is located or not
    public bool PushMove(Vector2 direction)
    {
        //We check if the movement of the push is going to be blocked by an obstacle or not
        if (ObjToBlock(transform.position, direction))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            transform.Translate(direction);
            return true;
        }
    }

    //We check if the pushable object is going to move where a obstacle is located or not
    public bool ObjToBlock(Vector3 pos, Vector2 direction)
    {
        //We calculate the new Position of the pushable object
        Vector2 newPos = new Vector2(pos.x, pos.y) + direction;

        foreach (var obstacle in NotMovableObj)
        {
            //If the pushable object is going to be in the position of an obstacle, we block its movement
            if (obstacle.transform.position.x == newPos.x && obstacle.transform.position.y == newPos.y)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        foreach (var pushable in MovableObj)
        {
            //We check if there's a second pushable object or an obstacle in the direction of the pushable object
            if (pushable.transform.position.x == newPos.x && pushable.transform.position.y == newPos.y)
            {
                // Calculate the new position of the second pushable object
                Vector2 newPushablePos = newPos + direction;

                foreach (var obstacle in NotMovableObj)
                {
                    // If there's an obstacle in the new position of the second pushable object, we block the movement of both pushable objects
                    if (obstacle.transform.position.x == newPushablePos.x && obstacle.transform.position.y == newPushablePos.y)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                foreach (var pushableNew in MovableObj)
                {
                    //We check if there's a second pushable object or an obstacle in the direction of the pushable object
                    if (pushableNew.transform.position.x == newPushablePos.x && pushableNew.transform.position.y == newPushablePos.y)
                    {
                        // Calculate the new position of the second pushable object adding the direction twice because it's twice as far from the original pushed object
                        Vector2 extraPushablePos = newPos + direction + direction;

                        foreach (var obstacle in NotMovableObj)
                        {
                            // If there's an obstacle in the new position of the second pushable object, we block the movement of both pushable objects
                            if (obstacle.transform.position.x == extraPushablePos.x && obstacle.transform.position.y == extraPushablePos.y)
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }

                        pushable.transform.Translate(direction);
                        pushableNew.transform.Translate(direction);
                        return false;

                    }
                }

                //We move the pushable in the desire direction if there's a second pushable object and no obstacles in their way
                pushable.transform.Translate(direction);
                return false;
            }
        }
        //If there's no obstacle, the pushable object can move freely
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Where do you get the `MovableObj` from? In general instead of hardcoding the amounts of adding the `direction` you should probably go recursive and check if when moving you hit something, if so check if also that hit object would hit something when also moving etc ... in the end you either end up with an object a) not hitting anything => fine to move b) hitting non-moveable => can not move or as said c) hitting another moveable => recursive check for that one

Comment: for the check if you would be hitting something easiest would probably be to use Colliders and [`Physics.OverlapBox`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapBox.html)